# Programmatically shutdown, restart, sleep in a sandboxed cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, shutdown, entitlements

I have a problem with the apple sandbox and the functionality of my app. The app should put my mac into sleep, or shutdown or restart it. I am using "com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events" as the entitlement for sandbox with the value "com.apple.finder". I have imported ScriptingBridge and generated a Finder.h file which i have also included in my project like its proposed in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/UsingScriptingBridge/UsingScriptingBridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH4-SW12

Then i tried to use the provided methods from Finder.h like shutDown, restart or sleep but they just don't work.

```
FinderApplication *theFinder = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.finder"];
[theFinder shutDown];
```

Can anyone tell me how i can implement these functionalities in a sandboxed app?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any messages on the console?  Is your `theFinder` nil? what diagnostics have you performed?

Comment: If your app is to be deployed in the Mac App Store, you will not get it approved with com.apple.finder in the temporary-exception. See also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975699/programmatically-shut-down-or-sleep-sandboxed-application-mac/21992945#21992945

Answer (score 1):

Checkout https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1134/_index.html

This guide provides the exact code you are looking for. I have tried this and it works perfectly.

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6105338/277952 for an updated version of Apple's code that works in 64bit (mine uses `AESendMessage()` instead of `AESend()`, which is 32-bit only). (I don't know if this is compatible with sandboxing or not).